# Catching errors listed in openssl/cert_vfy.h after calling SSL_CTX_use_certificate()

Tags: error-handling, openssl, certificate

Parsing pem certificates with OpenSSL can fail for various reasons after calling SSL_CTX_use_certificate(), listed as constants in openssl/x509_vfy.h, for instance X509_V_ERR_CA_MD_TOO_WEAK. In this case however, ERR_get_error() only returns 0x0A00018E, and SSL_get_error() doesn't apply to error handling of SSL_CTX_use_certificate() according to the documentation.

Calling ERR_print_error_fp(stderr) however prints X509_V_ERR_CA_MD_TOO_WEAK as the main problem in this case.

How can I catch individual errors as listed in openssl/err_vfy.h without parsing the text returned by ERR_print_error_fp()  (which I consider inelegant and non portable)?

Comment: I'm answering to myself: constants such as X509_V_ERR_CA_MD_TOO_WEAK cannot be caught because they are used internally. As it happens, the 18e component of the error code returned corresponds to SSL_R_CA_MD_TOO_WEAK, defined in openssl/sslerr.h, and can be extracted from it using ERR_GET_REASON(ERR_get_error()).